# Is there a way to run "explain" on bulk_write

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to profile my bulk_write since it is (currently) the slowest section of my code. I know that there is the "explain" operation on "find", is there a way to do it on bulk_write?

Answer (score 0):

Explain returns a *query plan*. Writes are not queries and thus have no query plans. Therefore writes cannot be explained the same way that queries are.

To troubleshoot write performance:

- Look at cpu usage in various states (interrupt, iowait)
- Look at disk i/o stats (iostat) - iops, transfer amount; compare to theoretical maximums, benchmark the same hardware (physical disks etc.) to figure out what your system can do with the hardware without the database being there
- Look at memory consumption and paging
- Look at server stats (I don't have any specific guidance here)